# split dictionary into two lists , one list is for key, another list is for value

Tags: python

I want to split dictionary into  two lists. one list is for key, another list is for value.

And it should be ordered as original

Original list:

```
[{"car":45845},{"house": 123}]
```

Expected result:

```
list1 = ["car", "house"]

list2 = [45845, 123]
```

Comment: what kinda crappy data structure is this? thats not a dictionary... thats a list of one element dictionaries

Comment: Agreed. What is the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fixed_list = [x.items() for x in list]
keys,values = zip(*fixed_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list1 = [k for item in [{"car":45845},{"house": 123}] for k,v in item.iteritems()]
list2 = [v for item in [{"car":45845},{"house": 123}] for k,v in item.iteritems()]
```

[For Python 3 use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418498/452708) `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()`

Comment: good readability gets +1 from me (even if you are iterating it twice as many times as you need to)

Comment: True but I'm leaving work so it is the fastest thing to do at this time

Answer (score 0):

```
a =[{"car":45845},{"house": 123}]

list1 = [i.values()[0] for i in a] #iterate over values 
list2=  [i.keys()[0] for i in a]   #iterate over keys
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
original = [{"car":45845},{"house": 123}]
a_dict = {}
for o in original:
    a_dict.update(o)
print a_dict
print a_dict.keys()
print a_dict.values()
```

Output:

```
{'car': 45845, 'house': 123}
['car', 'house']
[45845, 123]
```

Comment: this will not give the expected output in the case of duplicate keys (which may or may not be a valid concern) it also loses the original ordering (since dicts are unordered) which OP specifically asked to preserve